# How do i resize the buttons in Jquery DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

This is my datatable I used in my project. I want to resize that edit and delete buttons. I don't know how I do that. the problem is when there re more than 10 buildings the buttons disappers. This is what it looks like when there are more than 10 buildings.[image] I believe its the issue with the buttons.[image]

The code I had used is:

```
$("#building-dt").DataTable({
    "aProcessing": true,
    "aServerSide": true,
    "deferRender": true,
    'statesave': true,
    "bDestroy": true,
    responsive: true,
    "ajax": {
        "url": baseUrl + "getBuilding/",
        "dataSrc": ""
    },
    'fnCreatedRow': function(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
        $(nRow).attr('id', 'building-dt-' + aData.id);
    },
    "columns": [{

            "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                return meta.row + 1;
            }
        },
        {
            "data": "name"
        },
        {
            "data": "description"
        },



        {
            sortable: false,
            "width": "15%",
            "render": function(data, type, content, meta) {

                return '\n\
                            <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning btn-edit" onclick="ediBuildings(' + content.id + ')">\n\
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil" title="Edit"></i></a>\n\
                            <button onclick="deleteBuilding(' + content.id + ')"  id="image-delete" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger btn-delete" data-id="' + content.id + '">\n\
                                <i class="fa fa-trash" title="Delete"></i>\n\
                            </button>';

            }
        }
    ]
});
```

I want to know whether the problem is with the buttons or code. if it is with the buttons how do i resolve that?
thanks in advance.

Comment: You want to edit edit or delete button?

Comment: i want to resize the buttons. when there are more than 10 buildings te button disappears

Comment: Would you be able to fix the paging? If you are able to make the 11'th row go to another page (because it should be 1-10 rows of 11), then let us see what we can do. You might have a code that hides the buttons because the showing of list is wrong

Comment: where is mistake?